# Flutter: Better approach for sending bulk SMS without user interaction on Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sms, bulksms

In our project, we need to send bulk SMS to our entire customer list (around 200 users in the list), for their monthly dues.

We will:

1. send first sms to all users
2. second sms to pending payment users
3. final third message to remaining users

We can't use SMS Gateway with API, because the internet is not reliable in the area where this app will be used so we wanted to use SIM for the SMS.

**Questions:**

1. How can we send SMS without user interaction?
2. How we can prompt for SIM selection? (dual sim mobile)
3. Does using `Future` with `async` is good approach for sending BULK SMS OR is there any alternative available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should take runtime permission for SMS

Answers:

1. Then you can use this library to send sms
   [SMS LIBRARY](https://pub.dev/packages/sms).
2. You can also choose between dual sim in this library.
3. With help of this library based on sms is delivered or not you can handle BULK SMS.

Comment: thanks Deepak, I notice the SMS Library provides delivery report. Do you know if that is real time? I mean, is there any response from telecom operator about delivery or how it predicts/knows? Second thing, should I send SMS in parallel (calling send sms method inside recipient loop without waiting for any response) OR send sms and wait for it's satus; when status changes to sent then I should second message and so on?

Comment: I am not sure about the delivery report response but we can check by implementing and checking it live with real device mostly it will be actual delivery report that we get from stock message app which is based on telecom operator but making sure it actually does will be better. You can iterate through contacts which you want to send sms without waiting for response but add some callback or maintain list for failure who doesnt receive the message so that you can send them later.

Comment: how do I maintain list? If I'm calling method to send sms without any delay, then how do I keep track of messages with status failed or sent?

Comment: Pseudo code:
declare list of contacts whom you want to send sms as listContacts
declare list of contacts to maintain list of failed recipients as listFailed
declare string which contains message to be sent
iterate through listContacts
 use sms library to send sms listContacts[i]
  success->{
  }
  failure->{
   listFailed.add(listContacts[i]) 
  }

try to send sms again with listFailed contacts

Comment: awesome, thanks for your help! I'll give it try and will let you know if I have any problem.

Comment: That package doesnt work any more, and is unmaintained by the owner.