# Flutter package for sending bulk sms without launching sms app

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, sendmessage

In my application, there gonna be about 400 users and we need to send them an sms notification. And I'm searching for suitable package, I asked almost [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668027/flutter-better-approach-for-sending-bulk-sms-without-user-interaction-on-androi) about a month ago.

I was suggested [sms](https://pub.dev/packages/sms) package, but it doesn't support **iOS**. So I tried to look for other options, and I go through these packages:

1. **[sms_maintained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained)** (I guess it is the same package, but updated and maintained by different author)

**Issues with this package:**

1. Does not support `<21` SDK version
2. Does not find option to send bulk SMS (looping the `recipients` is an option but maybe resource extensive and also difficult to keep track of failed sms)
3. It supports a lot of options and prompt for `phone call` permissions, I just need permission to send sms; even don't need to read sms so most of it's feature are unnecessary in my project
4. **[flutter_sms](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms)**  This package is almost according to my needs because it is clean and only performs one function which I need. But it doesn't work in the background, it launches sms app.

**Q.** Does anyone knows any solution/package for this?

Comment: Do you want to send SMS from the App (for this, launching default SMS handler is a good option, as convincing Google/Apple to send SMS from your app is painful)? Or do you want to send SMS to your consumers who are using the App (for this, why not send SMS from the server, using SMS api like twilio etc)? If you don't want to use Twilio, have a look at https://www.sg.yagnyam.in/

Comment: First of all, this application gonna be used by only one organization, and its not going on play store or app store. Secondly, the location where this app gonna be used has un-reliable internet service; even sometime the cellular network goes away so using an API service is not an option. Also we need to keep track of message so launching SMS app doesn't seem convenient option, so I need another solution.

Comment: @Alena did you find a solution? If so, I would appreciate it if you could share it with us

Comment: @baselsader unfortunately, I didn't found a solution. Based on my findings we have to use third party API or allow SMS app launch hectic process.